# How to use android timer

Tags: android-layout, timer

I am developing an android app.In my main activity i have two layouts. 1st relative Layout which have visibility gone and after that one LinerLayout which is visible.In my activity class,I want to set the timer so that after 3 second my LinerLayout should be gone and RelativeLayout should be visible.How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `java.util.Timer` to achiever this.

For repeating task, use following:

`new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);`

For a single run of a task, use following:

`new Timer().schedule(task, after);`

task: Method that you to be executed. 
after: time interval  for initial execution of timer.(in milliseconds) 
interval: intermediate time to repeat alarm

for your reference:

```
class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
public void run() {
   firstLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   secondRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

To start timer:

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 3000);
```

Comment: you'll want a `runOnUiThread()` within `TimerTask.run()` otherwise, by updating the UI not using the main thread, you'll be greeted with a nice wet `CalledFromWrongThreadException`